# Filter get_user_by instead of replace function

Tags: plugin-development

I have developed a plugin (despite minor understanding) that replaces pluggable function `get_user_by` to pull userdata from another source. While this works, it can lead to maintenance whenever there is a new WP version with changes in the pluggable function. I learned with get_avatar that it is best to filter rather than replace.

Is there a means to filter `get_user_by` rather than replacing it?

For example, using add_filter like the following doesn't appear to work.

```
Class XenWord_Login {

    public $visitor;
    public $user_id;
    public $current_user;

    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'get_user_by', array( &$this, 'getUserData' ) );
    }

    function getUserData() {

        $visitor = XenWord::getVisitor();
        $user_id = $visitor['user_id'];
        $current_user = $visitor;

        $userdata = XenWord_XFUserData::xf_user_data( $visitor, $current_user,
        $user_id );

        if ( ! $userdata ) {
            return false;
        }

        $user = new WP_User;
        $user->init( $userdata );

        return $user;
    }
}

$login = new XenWord_Login();
```

The above is simply test code to try to filter rather than replace. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source `get_user_by()` is not too much more than a kind of interface to the `WP_User` object. You can see that it uses the methods 'get_data_by()`:

```
$userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( $field, $value );
```

And `init`:

```
$user = new WP_User;
$user->init( $userdata );
```

[Neither offer any filters.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L558)

[Nor does the cache object used by `get_data_by()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/cache.php#L0)

I don't see a way to do it without replacing that function. Maybe somebody can spot something I don't.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum. Since the point of replacing `get_user_by` is to have $userdata variable point to another source, would it be wiser to use `update_user_meta` and copy the information from the external source directly into the wp_usermeta table? Would `get_user_by` then pull that information? Thank you for thinking this through with me.

Comment: These are the fields that can be updated in the _users table: ID, user_pass, user_login, user_nicename, user_url, user_email, display_name, nickname, first_name, last_name, description, rich_editing, user_registered, role, show_admin_bar_front. Next, would be to use `user_contactmethods` for new meta data ...